# Cloud function migration of Cloud storage data, error: "reason: socket hang up"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I am migrating some files to cloud storage.

I have a cloud function that was doing the job when I test it with 5 files.

But now when I run the same cloud function where 50+ files need to be copied in a new place it returns the next error:

```
 Exception from a finished function: FetchError: request to https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/...-933ca.appspot.com/o?prefix=documents%123123123231321sadas failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

Cloud function code:

```
exports.updateStorage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await updateStorageData();

    res.send(200);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating storage data', error);
    return error;
  }
});


const updateStorageData = async () => {
  const db = admin.firestore();

  db.collection('users')
    .get()
    .then(userSnapshot => {
      userSnapshot.forEach(user => {
        const userId = user.id;

        const subCollectionRef = db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userId)
          .collection('documents');
        subCollectionRef
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
              await readFiles({ docId: doc.id, userId });
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
          });
      });
    });
};

async function readFiles({ docId, userId }) {
  const [files] = await admin
    .storage()
    .bucket()
    .getFiles({ prefix: `documents/${docId}` });

  if (files.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const promises = [];

  files.forEach(file => {
    promises.push(file.copy(`users/${userId}/${file.name}`));
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Function deatils:

- First gen function
- onRequest
- Memory 8GB
- I am runing the fucntion via "Testing" tab for testing function
- Function needs to go to firebase, fetch data, and update data in storage from one structure to new one

Any help very welcome